# Questions about ridge regression on python : Scaling, and interpretation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I tried to run a Ridge Regression on Boston housing data with python, but I had the following questions that I cannot find answer anywhere so I decided to post it here:

Is scaling recommended before fitting the model? Because I get the same score when I scale and when I don't scale. Also, what is the interpretation of the alpha/coeff graph in terms of choosing the best alpha?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_csv('../housing.data',delim_whitespace=True,header=None)
col_names = ['CRIM','ZN','INDUS','CHAS','NOX','RM','AGE','DIS','RAD','TAX','PTRATIO','B','LSTAT','MEDV']
df.columns = col_names
X = df.loc[:,df.columns!='MEDV']
col_X = X.columns 
y = df['MEDV'].values

# Feature Scaling:

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_std = scaler.fit_transform(X)
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
clf = Ridge()
coefs = []
alphas = np.logspace(-6, 6, 200)

for a in alphas:
    clf.set_params(alpha=a)
    clf.fit(X_std, y)
    coefs.append(clf.coef_)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))
plt.subplot(121)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(alphas, coefs) 
ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('alpha')
plt.ylabel('weights')
plt.title('Ridge coefficients as a function of the regularization')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

### [Alpha/coefficient graph for scaled X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inBU3.png)

### [Alpha/coefficient graph for unscaled X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeDUg.png)

On the scaled data, when I compute the score and choose the alpha thanks to CV, I get:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
clf = RidgeCV(alphas=[1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 5, 7]).fit(X_std, y)

> clf.score(X_std, y)
> 0.74038
> clf.alpha_
> 5.0
```

On the non-scaled data, I even get a slightly better score with a completely different alpha:

```
clf = RidgeCV(alphas=[1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 6]).fit(X, y)

> clf.score(X, y)
> 0.74064
> clf.alpha_
> 0.01
```

Thanks for your insights on the matter, looking forward to reading your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should scale because Ridge Regularization penalizes large values, and so you don't want to lose meaningful features because of scaling issues. Perhaps you don't see a difference because the housing data is a toy dataset and is already scaled well.

A larger alpha is a stronger penalty on large values. The graph is showing you (though it has no labeling) that with a stronger alpha you send coefficients to zero more strongly. The more gradual lines are the smaller weights, so they're effected less or almost not at all until alpha becomes sufficiently large. The sharper ones are larger weights, so they drop to zero more quickly. When they do, the feature will disappear from your regression.

Comment: Thanks, so basically an alpha too strong would erase all my independent variable's weight ? Sorry for the lack of labelling ! I did't see it when I uploaded the image

Comment: Exactly, sends the weight to zero so in your regression the variable completely disappears. If you don't want to lose your variables so quickly, try sklearn.linear_model.Lasso

Answer (score 0):

For the scaled data, the magnitude of design matrix is smaller, and the coefficients tend to be larger (and more L2 penalty is imposed). To minimize L2, we need more and more small coefficients. How to get more and more small coefficients? The way is to choose a very big alpha, so we can have more smaller coefficients. That is why if you scale the data, the optimal alpha is a great number.